# how to create Controls Automatically?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

i have a Questionnaire Project which contains Questions and Answers

example :

- Id_Questionnaire 1
- Question : how are you?
- Answer :Fine
- Answer :Good
- Answer :Bad

the number of the questions and answers is unlimited 
so i wonder how to create Labels for each Question and RadioButtons for each Answer ?

**" how to create controls dynamically according to number of questions , answers?"** 
if you have a project like this to help me , i'd be so thankful 
NOTE : It's all C# and ADO.NET not web (ASP.NET)
thank you ^^

Comment: What have you tried so far. Stackoverflow is for SPECIFIC programming questions, not general "How do I do this" questions. For example are you using WPF or Forms? What code have you written?

Comment: Hi man , it's Forms , 
the exact question is how to create controls dynamically according to number of questions , answers :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having trouble dynamically adding controls.  Assuming that you have retrieved your questions from the database, iterate each question and dynamically add the new controls.  [See this tutorial](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/windows-forms/dynamically-adding-controls).

for example...

```
foreach (Question q in MyQuestions)
{
    AddAQuestion(MyContainerControl, q.ID, q.QuestionText);
    AddPossibleAnswers(MyContainerControl, q.PossibleAnswers);
}
```